# Replace a substring with a StringBuffer substring

Tags: java, string, jsoup, stringbuffer

I have a Huge string which is complete html obtained into a string by JSOUP.I have made changes to a substring of the html using String Bufer replace API(replace(int startIndex,int endIndex, "to be changed string).The String buffer is populated perfectly.But when I try to replace the substring of html with new String buffer it does not work.

Here is the code snippet.

```
html = html.replace(divStyle1.trim(), heightwidthM.toString().trim());
```

The initial big html is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:og="http://opengraphprotocol.org/schema/" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en" class="SAF" id="global-header-light">
<head>

</head>
<body>


**<div style="background-image: url(http://aka-cdn-ns.adtech.de/rm/ads/23274/HPWomenLOFT_1381687318.jpg);background-repeat: no-repeat;-webkit-background-size: 1001px 2059px; height: 2059px; width: 1001px; text-align: center; margin: 0 auto;">**                      

<div style="height:2058px; padding-left:0px; padding-top:36px;">


<iframe style="height:90px; width:728px;"/>



</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

The divStyle1 string is

```
background-image: url(http://aka-cdn-ns.adtech.de/rm/ads/23274/HPWomenLOFT_1381687318.jpg);background-repeat: no-repeat;-webkit-background-size: 1001px 2059px; height: 2059px; width: 1001px; text-align: center; margin: 0 auto;
```

And the String buffer has value

background-image: url(http://aka-cdn-ns.adtech.de/rm/ads/23274/HPWomenLOFT_1381687318.jpg);background-repeat: no-repeat;-webkit-background-size: 1001px 2059px; height:720px; width:900px; text-align: center; margin: 0 auto;

does not work where divStyle is a substring of the last HTML(in String) and heightwidthM is a Stringbuffer value with which it has to be replaced.It doesnt throw any errors but it does not change it as well.

Thanks
Swaraj

Comment: What are the values?  If `html` is huge, just post the relevant part of the string.  Are you sure that there is an exact match?

Comment: considering that you are using jsoup, and jsoup makes your life easier working with html documents, why not create a `org.jsoup.nodes.Document` off your html, find the tag that you need and modify it in place?

Comment: @rgettman Made the required edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very easy with JSoup

```
String html = "<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html xmlns:og=\"http://opengraphprotocol.org/schema/\" xmlns:fb=\"http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml\" xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\" xml:lang=\"en\" lang=\"en\" class=\"SAF\" id=\"global-header-light\">\n<head>\n\n</head>\n<body>\n\n\n**<div style=\"background-image: url(http://aka-cdn-ns.adtech.de/rm/ads/23274/HPWomenLOFT_1381687318.jpg);background-repeat: no-repeat;-webkit-background-size: 1001px 2059px; height: 2059px; width: 1001px; text-align: center; margin: 0 auto;\">**                      \n\n<div style=\"height:2058px; padding-left:0px; padding-top:36px;\">\n\n\n<iframe style=\"height:90px; width:728px;\"/>\n\n\n\n</div>\n</div>\n\n</body>\n</html>";
String newStyle = "background-image: url(http://aka-cdn-ns.adtech.de/rm/ads/23274/HPWomenLOFT_1381687318.jpg);background-repeat: no-repeat;-webkit-background-size: 1001px 2059px; height:720px; width:900px; text-align: center; margin: 0 auto;";

Document document = Jsoup.parse(html);
document.body().child(0).attr("style", newStyle);
System.out.println(document.html());
```

Answer (score 0):

Coming back to my suggestion, if you don't mind trying, you can do something of this sort:

```
Document newDocument = Jsoup.parse(<your html string>, StringUtils.EMPTY, Parser.htmlParser());
Elements yourStyles = newDocument.select("div[style]"); // this will select all div with attributes style
yourStyles.get(0).attr("style", <your new value>); // this will get your first div and replace attribute style to your new value
System.out.println(newDocument.outerHtml());
```